# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have copied this sample app https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

I followed all the instructions in creating `SHA1`, setup correctly in `Google developer console`.

I was having some issues with the `google play services` (I think it was stopping) and to solve it, I right-clicked on the `app > Android tools > Export Signed application package`.

I installed in my `Samsung phone`. When I started it, it asked me to select a `Gmail` account, which I did. Then I selected `Create a folder` from the `ListView`,
The message `Signing in...This can take a few minutes` showed up and never ever able to sign in successfully. It was almost more than 30 minutes and still going on.

I checked the `Logcat` in `Eclipse` and I have the following logs.
**How to solve this?**

```
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3784)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:5008)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3423)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3315)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2122)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/firstparty/shared/PACLConfig
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     ... 19 more
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig" on path: .
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-22 21:38:54.677: E/Parcel(2395):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: Do you use `Proguard` or any obfuscation tool on your code ? Please check the `project.properties` file in your application?

Comment: @manitoba: Yes, I'm using proguard and the project.properties has the following codes:

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib

What should I do then?

Comment: Did you install the Google Play Services SDK?  http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @EricKoleda Yes I did install it. I have been using it to my other location app.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `proguard`to obsfucaste your code, add the following exception to your `proguard file`:

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have those on my proguard file. As I have mentioned, this sample app is called Google Drive Android Demos, which can be found in [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/)
I just don't know on what to do now. It is also happening in all of those samples mentioned from the link...Very frustrating.
I would really appreciate so much (I have appreciated already in replying) if you can come up with a solution, which even google search can't show anything. It is a new issue...Thanks

Comment: any help out there please?

Comment: Could you try to compile it without proguard enabled ?

Comment: No luck. The screen is showing "Signing in...This can take a few minutes"....and the log is showing the same stuff I posted...

Comment: I have been watching the log while it is trying to connect. I have noticed the following and it is about Token. Maybe there is something missing on the instructions from Google:

05-30 19:42:54.450: E/Parcel(2399): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/firstparty/dataservice/TokenRequest
05-30 19:42:54.450: E/Parcel(2399):  ... 18 more
05-30 19:42:54.450: E/Parcel(2399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.dataservice.TokenRequest" on path: